# jQuery ajax call Returning particular HTML elements

Tags: jquery, html

I tried this code:

```
$.post('/script', function(result) {
    var foo = $(result).find('#foo');
    $('#result').html(foo);
});
```

Here's the return html:

```
<div id='foo'>
  Content.
</div>
<div id='new'>
   New data
</div>
```

After alerting variable foo it returns an object. And the html becomes empty. I would like to print a specific html block (#foo only not #new).

From jQuery documentation:

```
$.post( url, { s: term } ,
      function( data ) {
          var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
          $( "#result" ).html( content );
      }
);
```

This (var content) would also result to object and printing an empty string on #result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because both `#foo` and `#new` are at the top level.

The `.find()` method looks for descendants. so you will need to wrap them in another div either at the server-side (*result*) or the jQuery level.

So either change html to

```
<div>
   <div id='foo'>
     Content.
   </div>
   <div id='new'>
      New data
   </div>
</div>
```

**or** at jquery level

```
$.post('/script', function(result) {
    var foo = $(result).wrapAll('<div>').parent().find('#foo');
    $('#result').html(foo);
});
```

If you use the HTML solutions you could however use the `.load` method which can load page fragments

```
$('#result').load('/script #foo');
```

This will load the element with id `foo` from the `/script` page and put it in `#result` element.

Comment: but i want to retrieve the contents of #foo only leaving the #new div

Comment: @markcruz, that is what this code does (*all versions do select the #foo element only. It is just that you have to prepare the data a bit.*)

Answer (score 0):

foo is an object... foo.html() is what you want, so you've to change :
$('#result').html(foo);
in
$('#result').html(foo.html());